# Is it possible to display other widgets with WebViewWidget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, webview

I am using the the [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) plugin with [ready player me](https://docs.readyplayer.me/ready-player-me/integration-guides/web-and-native-integration/integration-examples/web). I am trying to display a webview with a 3d model in it which works great. The problem is I only want this WebViewWidget to cover up the upper half of the screen while having other widgets below this.

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 
'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class PlayerTest extends StatefulWidget {
  const PlayerTest({super.key});

  @override
  State<PlayerTest> createState() => 
_PlayerTestState();
}

class _PlayerTestState extends State<PlayerTest> {
  late WebViewController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = WebViewController()
   
   
   
  ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
      ..setBackgroundColor(const Color(0xFFFF0000))
  ..setNavigationDelegate(
    NavigationDelegate(
      onProgress: (int progress) {
        // update loading bar
      },
      onPageStarted: (String url) {},
      onPageFinished: (String url) {},
      onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError error) {},
      onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) {
        if (request.url.startsWith("https://google.com")) {
          return NavigationDecision.prevent;
        }
        return NavigationDecision.navigate;
      },
    ),
  )
  ..loadRequest(Uri.parse('https://www.youtube.com/'));
controller.loadFlutterAsset('assets/playatest.html');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        const Text("Anotha one"),
        const SizedBox(height: 50),
        WebViewWidget(
          controller: controller,
        ),
        const Text("This is my text boiiiii"),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

When I run this code my app freezes and gives me no errors so i'm not sure what the problem is. Is it possible to use a webviewwidget with other widgets in a column? The WebViewWidget runs fine when that is the only thing present, but when other widgets are combined it freezes the app.